# Text does not appear on buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to create four buttons where four labels appear in a random order:

```
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice0"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice1"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice2"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice3"></button>
</div>
```

The labels are stored under the

```
var choiceLabels = ["Hola", "Hole", "Holo", "Holu"];
```

Then the code iterates through the choices to stick them in the buttons:

```
for (var i=0; i<choiceLabels; i++) {
    var theID="#quizChoice"+i.toString();
    $(theID).text(choiceLabels[i])
};
```

But the text does not appear on the buttons - they stay empty.
Anybody know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here: `i<choiceLabels`. `choiceLabels` is an array, so you have to do `i<choiceLabels.length`.

```js
var choiceLabels = ["Hola", "Hole", "Holo", "Holu"];
for (var i=0; i<choiceLabels.length; i++) {
    var theID="#quizChoice"+i.toString();
    $(theID).text(choiceLabels[i])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice0"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice1"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice2"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice3"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `length` value in `choiceLabels`. The iteration should loop through `choiceLabels.length`:

```js
var choiceLabels = ["Hola", "Hole", "Holo", "Holu"];

for (var i=0; i<choiceLabels.length; i++) {
    var theID="#quizChoice"+i.toString();
    $(theID).text(choiceLabels[i])
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice0"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice1"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice2"></button>
</div>
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice3"></button>
</div>
```